# how to embedded current element into a new element and updated into document with jsoup

Tags: java, jsoup

i'm using jsoup dealing with html and I want to embedded <img> element into <p>
from:

```
<div>
   <img src="image.jpg"/>
</div>
```

to:

```
<div>
   <p><img src="image.jpg"/><br></p>
</div>
```

I tried using under code but can not updated into the jsoup document

```
@Test
public void testaddp(){
    String acontent = "<div><img src="/base/img/avs.jpg"/></div>";
    Document document = Jsoup.parseBodyFragment(acontent);
    Element element = document.body();
    Element imgelement = element.select("img").first();
    Element newElement = new Element("p");
    newElement = newElement.insertChildren(0,imgelement,new Element("br"));
    System.out.println(newElement.outerHtml());//seems i got the correct html in newElement
    //imgelement.replaceWith(newElement);//failed to update into element
    imgelement.wrap(newElement.outerHtml());//also failed to update into element
    //how to updated into document?
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: use imgelement.wrap("<p>") instead of imgelement.wrap(newElement.outerHtml()); can add <p></p>outer the img tag in document. But how to add<br> after<img/>?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with this code. Explanation in comments.

```
    String acontent = "<head>Some head</head><body><div>A div</div><div><img src=\"/base/img/avs.jpg\"/></div><div>Another div</div></body>";
    Document document = Jsoup.parse(acontent);
    System.out.println(document);
    //select element you want to change
    Element img = document.select("img").first();
    //wrap it with p
    Element p = new Element("p");
    p.html(img.outerHtml());
    //append br
    Element br = new Element("br");
    p.appendChild(br);
    //replace original with new
    img.replaceWith(p);

    System.out.println(document);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found one answer:

```
@Test
public void testaddp(){
    String acontent = "<div><img src="/base/img/avs.jpg"/></div>";
    Document document = Jsoup.parseBodyFragment(acontent);
    Element element = document.body();
    Element imgelement = element.select("img").first();

    //find parent element
    Element parentElement = imgelement.parent();
    //add br after img tag
    parentElement.insertChildren(parentElement.childNodeSize(),new Element("br"));

    //add p tag out of img
    imgelement.wrap("<p>")

    System.out.println();
}
```